# lodash: error chaining mapValues

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm struggling to chain `_.mapValues`. This is the code

```
var result = _.mapValues(results[0], function(val, qname) {
    return (results[1].hasOwnProperty(qname)) ? _.assign(val, results[1][qname]) : val
})
.mapValues(function(r) {r.total = addFields(r); return r;})
```

which is resulting in a runtime `TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'mapValues'` for the second mapValues. The first mapValues is working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, you need use method [`_.chain`](https://lodash.com/docs#chain), like this

```
var result = _.chain(results[0])
   .mapValues(function(val, qname) {
       return (results[1].hasOwnProperty(qname)) ? _.assign(val, results[1][qname]) : val
   })
   .mapValues(function(r) {r.total = addFields(r); return r;})
   .value();
```